# Jquery Datatables does not accept valid JSON data : SignalR MVC - Real time data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, signalr

Script on the client that has the functions calls to Initialise the Datatable on SignalR.connection.Start and get UpdatedData from the hub on sqldependency change.

```
$(function () {
// Reference the hub.
var hubNotif = $.connection.RunningPOHub;

// Start the connection.
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    getAll();
});

// Notify while anyChanges.
hubNotif.client.updatedData = function (data) {
    getUpdatedData(data);
}
});

function getAll() {

$('#demoGrid').dataTable({
    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
    "serverSide": true, // for process server side
    "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
    "pageLength": 2,
    "responsive": true,

    "ajax": {
        "url": "/RunningPO/GetData",
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    "columns": [
                  { "data": "Unit", "name": "Unit", "autoWidth": true },
                  { "data": "PO_NO", "name": "PO_NO", "autoWidth": true },
                  { "data": "QUANTITY_AV", "title": "Quantity", "name": "QUANTITY_AV", "autoWidth": true }
    ],
});
}

function getUpdatedData(data) {
var jdata= JSON.stringify(data);
alert(JSON.stringify(data));//Please see the attached screenshot and JSON 
                                                  //response shown below.
debugger;
$('#demoGrid').dataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "processing": true, // for show progress bar
    "serverSide": true, // for process server side
    "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
    "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
    "pageLength": 2,
    "responsive": true,
    "data": jdata,

    "columns": [
                  { "data": "Unit", "name": "Unit", "autoWidth": true },
                  { "data": "PO_NO", "name": "PO_NO", "autoWidth": true },
                  { "data": "QUANTITY_AV", "title": "Quantity", "name": "QUANTITY_AV", "autoWidth": true }
    ],
});
}
```

JSON response obtained from the server.

[image: JSON Response]

```
[
    {"PO_NO":"237","Unit":"TSD-1","QUANTITY_AV":"123.45"},
    {"PO_NO":"5","Unit":"TSD-2","QUANTITY_AV":"765.90"},
    {"PO_NO":"25","Unit":"TSD-3","QUANTITY_AV":"78998"}
]
```

The data gets loaded (as attached below) in the initial getAll() function where the data is received from the internal ajax call to the Controller/ActionMethod.

[image: Initial Datatable]

When the response is received from the server through SignalR Hub and loaded to the `$('#demoGrid').dataTable({})` in getUpdatedData(data) function. The jquery-Datatable throws error

> Invalid JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json must be like this :

```
{
data: [
    {"PO_NO":"237","Unit":"TSD-1","QUANTITY_AV":"123.45"},
    {"PO_NO":"5","Unit":"TSD-2","QUANTITY_AV":"765.90"},
    {"PO_NO":"25","Unit":"TSD-3","QUANTITY_AV":"78998"}
    ]
}
```

the data json must contain a data attribut contain your list

Comment: You are right  Thank you for the quick response.. The data went thru fine without the JSON.stringify method.